Color filter. I need a library
I'm trying to make a color filter for screen but don't know how 2 edit pixels with speed, that will be enough for user don't noticed about change, but without using all resources of cpu or gpu (for example, timer for 1/fps secs). & for optimization will be useful to know where screen was reloaded

Start by picking one language, preferably the one you know the best, and it will become much easier to find documentation and tutorials. And asking questions, here or elsewhere.

And you can do it with a window, where you simply make it either borderless or draw on the borders. You can even create windows without a titlebar.

Create a transparent window that covers the whole screen and draw on that. Or a 'desktop window' may already exist and you can try drawing on that.

Are you looking for something similar to this: [SO]: Square in Python GDI (with PatBLT) (@CristiFati's answer)? Also note that the particular area of the screen might (will) be redrawn by other applications which are not under your control.

@CristiFati, yes, something like this, but i can't find in docs, how 2 set value to a pixel, not invert it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

On Windows, you can use the GetDC function, defined in Windows.h.
#include <Windows.h>
int main(){
    while (true){
       HDC screenDC = ::GetDC(0);
       ::Rectangle(screenDC, 200, 200, 300, 300);
       ::ReleaseDC(0, screenDC);
    }
}

How to draw to screen in c++?

Thst's literally that i searched for! But is there any way to make it faster? With real frametime speen

Note that drawing like this is not persistent. The next screen refresh will overwrite the drawing. You have to redraw it over and over to keep it onscreen for any reasonable amount of time. And you may as well create a window to draw on to make that more stable/safer.

@Grisha_Crysta 'What do you mean With real frametime speen'? If you're meaning for the box to persist, you need to put it in a loop.

@RemyLebeau OP asked to draw without a square outside of a window.

@somebodywhodoesntknowmuch I know that, I can read. I'm saying that even if the OP does draw directly on the screen, it won't persist very very long, so they would need a loop that redraws the square every time the screen is refreshed.

@somebodywhodoesntknowmuch you're right, but i need a lot's of squares & drawing of them seems like this: https://pastebin.com/NjQw9i4B
& squares is a just analogue

@RemyLebeau Edited answer.

@Grisha_Crysta Probably because the screen is being refreshed, then your square is being drawn. You can prevent this by simply using a window instead.

@somebodywhodoesntknowmuch your edit makes the situation worse, because now you have introduced a busy loop that eats up CPU cycles, pegging the CPU with high load unnecessarily.

@somebodywhodoesntknowmuch  even if i will use a window, i either i need to refresh it every frame

Yes, but using a graphics library will allow you to choose the order of drawing things and screen refreshes.
